# What is the number of n-digit numbers that can be written with the numbers 2, 3 and 4 that add up to be odd?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, examples-counterexamples, combinatorics-on-words

What is the number of 4-digit numbers that can be written with the numbers 2, 3 and 4 that add up to be odd?

for example:
3-23-32-43-34-223-243-232-234-322-324-342-344-...
...
n-digit numbers.

Comment: Try to prove by induction that the answer is $\frac12(3^n-1)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers with digits from $\{2,3,4\}$ with an odd number of $3$s.  Consider two mutually exclusive cases:

1. If the first $n-1$ digits contain an odd number of $3$s, the $n$th digit must be $2$ or $4$.
2. If the first $n-1$ digits contain an even number of $3$s, the $n$th digit must be $3$.

These two cases imply that
$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + (3^{n-1}-a_{n-1}) = a_{n-1} + 3^{n-1}.$$
The initial condition is $a_0=0$, and iterating the recurrence yields
$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^k = \frac{3^n-1}{3-1} = \frac{3^n-1}{2}.$$